# How can I change the font size of problems tab?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have added

```
    "editor.fontSize": 16,
    "markdown.preview.fontSize": 16,
    "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 16,
    "debug.console.fontSize": 16,
```

to my `settings.json` so that my editor, markdown previewer, integrated terminal, and debug console have font size 16. But I have no idea how to customize the font size of the problems tab. Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

As of June 2021, there is no setting for this. You got them all.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

:(

Comment: Is there any method to do it other than modifying `settings.json`? Since VSCode is open source, there should be somewhere to do such modification. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Damn, this sucks.